# How can I allow external plugins to add options to my menu bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, plugins

I am trying to create a plugin architecture for my application. I want that a developer can create plugins for my application and that plugins add different functionality to my application.

I want those plugins to add new items to my menu bar. How can I make such an architecture?

Comment: Maybe this help, it gives you the main idea: http://androidsrc.net/creating-android-app-plugin-architecture-tutorial/

Comment: @FarShaD I have already seen this link. It is just searching for external applications and calling them. I want that plugins add functionality to my main application like menu items.

Comment: You want to add functionality to your app using the plugin packages that the user will install on device later, right ?

Comment: If this is what you want check these links, I thinks these are the best examples that show the concept clearly, It helped me a lot : http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/plugins.html

Comment: And this one : http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/plugins-with-user-interface.html

Comment: @FarShaD Yes. I don't want to package every thing into my application by default. So I want a plugin architecture.